# How to provide a default image file for ImageCache to use and process when the original does not exist?

Tags: drupal

Is there away to get ImageCache to use a default image? Or using htaccess to provide a default image to imagecache to process? Some of our clients sites are >4GB's and it's very painful dealing with all of their images that we don't need for development. I've tried using htaccess but ImageCache does not process the file and just ends up using the files dimensions which screws up the layout.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by default image...? When an image does not exist, well, it does not exit and imageCache, i think does not have to process anything which is really not dumb !
Do you mean default image for something like cck imagefield ?

Comment: When an image is missing I would like apache to provide a different file for PHP/Drupal/ImageCache to process and server up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand ImageCache responds to URIs like

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/default/files/imagecache/set/images/pic.png
```

where `http://www.yourdomain.com` is your domain, `files/imagecache` is the imagecache path, `set` is the predefined set of image manipulation settings and the rest (here: `images/pic.png`) is the actual relative path of the original image.

So, if pic.png doesn't exist, another file (default.png) should be served to ImageCache. An .htaccess solution for non-existant files could be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.[gif|jpg|png]$ /images/default.png [L]
```

Now ImageCache requests `images/pic.png` which does not exist and gets `images/default.png` served, processes it and saves it at `default/files/imagecache/set/images/pic.png`.

Well, at least this is my theory.

Regards, Paul

-###########-

EDIT regarding first comment:
Ok, I looked into the module. In `imagecache.module`, line 386 starts the helper function `_imagecache_cache($presetname, $path)`. Within this function is a check for the existance of original file (line 403). Change this block

```
  // Check if the path to the file exists.
  if (!is_file($src) && !is_file($src = file_create_path($src))) {
    watchdog('imagecache', '404: Unable to find %image ', array('%image' => $src), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit;
  };
```

to

```
  // Check if the path to the file exists.
  if (!is_file($src) && !is_file($src = file_create_path($src))) {
    watchdog('imagecache', '404: Unable to find %image ', array('%image' => $src), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
    /*header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit;*/
    $src = 'sites/all/modules/imagecache/sample.png';
  };
```

(Notes: I left the original code lines as comments. You can set $src to any default file you want.)

Comment: Paul, I've implemented an htaccess solution but the problem with it is ImageCache does not process the file. Instead it just passes it straight-through. I think it's because PHP is accessing the file from the filesystem and not through Apache. I may just have to make a change ImageCache directly.

Comment: Hi fadeddata, I see the problem and added a PHP based solution, just see my post above. Tested it and works like a charm. By leaving the watchdog line it even still reports missing images.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a module for this because I too hated working with broken layouts and I hated pulling down giant files directories to get 1-10GB+ of images just to fix the layout.

It works on the theme layer by wrapping theme('imagecache') and theme('image_style') calls in a bit of logic to detect broken paths. Also works with image formatters as well as theme functions.

http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_defaults

Works for Drupal 6 and 7.

Hitting the file system extra times for every image can be slow for some server configurations (http://drupal.org/node/908282) so imagecache_defaults persistently caches everything it discovers about files on your server and a few other things (use a non-db cache implementation for best results).